# Chicken thighs that don't seem right

Tags: food-safety, chicken

I bought chicken thighs from a large super market, portioned them and froze them for future use. (bought 2 weeks ago) I defrosted a pound in the fridge today, and as I was getting ready to trim the fat and dice the thighs, I noticed bright red blood "forming" a gritty film on top. These are boneless, skinless mind you, and there wasn't blood on or in the chicken (that I saw) when I froze, then thawed them.
To make it more unusual, it was like a film that I could peel and scrub off. As I was scrubbing the blood off under running water, I noticed one of the thighs looked like it had a rash maybe? I don't know now to explain it.. Like it had blisters that have been sloughed off or healed? Divots in the skin, in round circles, in a couple of patches.

If I scrub or cut away that part of the chicken, is it still ok to eat? I've honestly never seen this before in my 35 years.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get pictures?   Remember food service rule no. 2:  When in doubt, throw it out.

Comment: I took several pictures, but they didn't seem to come out well. 

http://s1354.photobucket.com/user/Yokai_chan/media/bloodychicken_zps12d4c43e.jpg.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is Rule 1? Is it "FiFo"?

Comment: Rule no 1:  If you have time to lean, you have time to clean.

Comment: LMAO!! I love it! I wonder if my son will go for that rule around the house.. =) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably safe, but I wouldn't want to eat it! You aren't facing starvation, so throw it away.

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right. It sort of bugs me though, because as a single mom, it's painful to waste money. Though this definitely solidifies that I will NEVER buy meat from Albertson's again. Every time I buy meat from their butcher section, at least half, if not most, is just well hidden, rotten meat. (like they will put the nice side out, and then when you get home and open the package that night, it's RANCID. I always check the dates and get something with a few days out on it, to ensure freshness.)
If I didn't already have that experience, I wouldn't doubt this chicken as much.

Comment: It's never nice to throw food away, especially when money is tight! Still, as someone who has had food poisoning from chicken I'd always err on the side of caution

Comment: Return it! Most grocery stores are willing to exchange out bad product at the very least.

Comment: It is probably better to cut some of the meat from your diet, and buy better meat when you do eat it.  If you have $30 a week budgeted to meat, you can buy 4-7 pounds of supermarket stuff at your own risk, or you can find a local butcher with a good reputation and buy half as much of a higher quality product.  Find ways to stretch it, or substitue beans and lentils on non-meat nights.  Many butcher shops also have 'freezer packs', where they give you a variety of cuts in 20-50 pound lots, wrapped as you like and freezer ready.  You get a decent product at a decent price.